# How to copy the rotation of a vertex group consistently

Tags: vertex-groups

I wasn't planning on spending hours on what is seemingly a simple task but here we go.

I created a cylinder (without top and bottom faces) and made a vertex group from one of the edge loops of the cylinder, then I applied a simple deform to bend the cylinder. Now I want to get the location and rotation of the vertex group (say, the top of the cylinder that's 'most deformed' by the bend). For this I tried copy constraints and childOf constraints targeting the vertex group, and even vertex parenting to three of the vertices, with similar results. Location is fine, but the rotation is jittering a bit when changing the bend angle, and at small bend angles it goes completely haywire, flipping as much as 180 degrees - on random axes no less.

This is my vertex group:
[image: selected vertex group]

An empty constrained to this vertex group with a ChildOf constraint, with X pointing away from the screen:
[image: with empty]

Note that since I started with a cylinder (with a loop cut) the vertices are fairly planar. Now applying a slight bend to the cylinder (1.6 degrees in this case) results in...
[image: mess]

I expected at least one of the axes to be roughly perpendicular to the vertex group even if they flip when going through negative to positive bend angle.

What I'd like to do is place objects at various points along the cylinder aligned to the cylinder's bend at that point - I have some workarounds for now but I'm curious about the wildly various rotations I end up with in this particular case.

Is there a better way to calculate this rotation?

Comment: I think this question could get some more attention if you try to illustrate what you need with a sketch or something.

Comment: Fair point, added some screenshots and clarification

Comment: I'd use more constraints: one for location and another for tracking end of cylinder, which can represented by additional vertex group or parented Empty

Comment: Yeah that's a fair point - a track constraint to the next edge loop does approximate the bend angle well enough. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.